# Can Angular package-lock.json lock nested dependencies?

Tags: angular, package-lock.json

**Angular CLI:** 11.0.3
**Angular:** 11.0.9
**Node:** 14.20.1
**Ivy Workspace:** Yes

I need package A, it requires package B, which requires package C.

The package B -> C dependency is expressed as ^2.0.12

I'd like to lock that dependency to 2.0.10

Can I add this to package-lock.json to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

In the package.json you can use

- if you use yarn the `resolutions` part for this
- if you use npm the
  `overrides` part for this

in package A with yarn :

```
  "resolutions": {
     "C": "2.0.10"
  }
```

in package A with npm :

```
"overrides": {
     "C": "2.0.10"
}
```

Comment: "resolutions" is observed by yarn, I see there is an npm equivalent "overrides"

Comment: yes you are right it depends on system used to install the package.json i edit my reply in consequencies